# Robot keyword that when script is executed i can enter values like opening a prompt

Tags: automation, robotframework

i'm trying to implement an AT that will start running a script and in next step when prompt is opened i can enter values.
Is there any library or keyword that will help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Dialogs library - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html

However, sometimes that fails if the user has not installed Tk along with python itself which i've seen few times in Windows.